# CIFS automount works on ubuntu 12 but not ubuntu 16

Tags: server, mount, samba, automount, cifs

I'm trying to migrate a server from ubuntu 12 to ubuntu 16 and there is an automount being used to connect to a SLES 11 ftp server.  I copied the configs from the u12 server to the u16.

#### Packages:

u12 autofs: *5.0.6-0ubuntu5.1*

u16 autofs: *5.1.1-1ubuntu3.1*

sles11 samba: *samba-3.6.3-94.14.2*

**/etc/auto.master:**

```
/media/mountpoint /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=120 --ghost
```

**/etc/auto.cifs:**

```
ach -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/etc/.smbcreds       ://ftpserver/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

The autofs service works fine in U12 but when I port it over to U16 I get errors.  I can however mount this manually using the following command:

```
mount -vvv -t cifs -o ver=1,user=sambauser,domain=domain1,prefixpath=dir2/dir3 //ftpserver/dir1/dir2/dir3 /media/mountpoint/localdir/
```

That line works and I can connect to the share on both servers with it.

The FTP server sees the connection attempt but the samba log reports either no such user or password.  Being I can connect manually with the same privileges that makes no sense to me.

**u16 /var/log/kern.log:**

> Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
>
> CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
>
> CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

**sles11 /var/log/samba/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.log:**

> [2018/10/19 10:18:54.456783,  0] auth/auth_domain.c:331(DOMAIN_client_validate)
>    domain_client_validate: unable to validate password for user domain\user in domain DOMAIN to Domain controller DC.example.com. Error was NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER.
>   [2018/10/19 10:18:54.459043,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
>     check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [DOMAIN\user] -> [localuser] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER

I have tried several different combinations of changing auto.cifs, adding creds manually to the entry in the file, changing parameters, etc, but I'm having no luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

p.s. being this is a sensitive server I've redacted identifying info.  If this causes ambiguity please let me know and I'll try to clarify as best as I can without releasing sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  It turns out the way auto.cifs works changed syntax.  Previously it would accept the domain and user on the same line in a credentials file.

For example:

```
username=somedomain\someuser
password=somepassword
```

With U16 they are now separate lines.

```
username=someuser
password=somepassword
domain=somedomain
```

Once the credentials file used the correct file syntax the problem was resolved.